# Store and query Fields with Redis

Tags: database, indexing, redis, sphinx, in-memory-database

I want to store in redis thousands of records with these fields :

```
User_id: int64;
latitude: float;
longitude: float;
age: int32;
height: int32
```

and later i want to retrieve all `user_id` of people that are close to **(lat:x,lng:y)** with age between **30 to 40**

Is it possible to do this with redis ? Else what are the list of `memory database` that can permit this ?

Comment: If you want a really efficient system perhaps use a dedicated spatial index, eg a RTree. A useful implementation might be like http://toblerity.org/rtree/. Interestingly you could map age, and height as dimensions in the data, and run multiple-dimenisional queries.

Comment: thanks barryhunter, but why such memory database engine didn't exist (yet)? sphinx can do well this job if it's was not fully oriented full text indexing :(

Comment: I disagree that sphinx is 'fully' orientated to full text indexing, it may be 'particularly *suited* to', but it can do *other* types of queries too very well. (as **demonstrated** in the reply to your other thread!) - I use sphinx for many queries that are not actually 'full-text' based, (**including** 'finding stuff nearby', like you example!!!?)

Comment: @barryhunter: sorry yes i agree you are right about sphinx, we use it internally for many years, but the updates is little complicate (need to merge xml), i know their is also RT index that i never try but anyway. Another think i don't like with sphinx is that we need the mysql client dll, this dll is horrible :( yes an http json interface was introduced but look like never really finished (must be bson instead of json to be fully optimized).

Comment: @barryhunter: last think, if i make no mistake sphinx don't create any index (except on the text), it's full scan all the rows in memory to filter them. I would like one database that a least use one index to filter the rows + full scan of attributes on this set

Comment: Since Sphinx 3.0.1 you can create an index by an attribute.

Comment: Manticore Search (fork of Sphinx) has much more powerful HTTP JSON interface (similar to Elastic's)

Comment: @Manticore-Sphinxnextgen yes but it's still json :( parsing json is little cpu intensive, a much more better way will be to return bson, that is compressed and easy to parse ...

Comment: Can also fake an index using keywords. Can even be done in two dimensions, with the likes of geohash. But if json is already too slow, doubt you would like this solution.

Comment: @barryhunter it's not that json is "too" slow, it's just that with a very little effort it's could be much more efficient :). about faking an index using keywords yes a know about this, but it's look like not very efficient too, keyword are stored on disk (as i know).

Comment: @barryhunter: what i would like is to have in memory one table with theses field: User_id, latitude, longitude, age and height and then 2 index, one on User_id to update/insert/delete row and another on latitude/longitude to apply the 1rt filter and the second filter (age, height, etc.) will be done be full scan on the top of the result of the 1rt filter. i don't understand why their is no such system already :(

Comment: I still dont understand what you got against sphinx/manticore. It can do it just fine. Can return results 1..20 (first page) in a 'nearby' query with sphinx "total_found":"1244","time":"0.032" - that is without any 'full-text' keywords. Using GEODIST to sort the rows to and filter to within 2km. The index has 5.7 million rows. Add a single numberic attribute filter and "total_found":"456","time":"0.026" (production server, so running many concurrent queries)

Comment: @barryhunter: why their is many fork (like manticore) of sphinx ? It's little think for sphinx but it's the need of libmysqlClient.dll that worried me :( after i never try the RT index, i must try !

Comment: Forks are common in OS projects. Sphinx as basically two. CouchDB has at least 5. As for the mysql client, others are available. Or just API or HTTP protocol instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to this efficiently, easily and with Redis if you use http://redisearch.io

Disclaimer: I work for Redis Labs, where RediSearch is developed.

If you have thing set up, you could do something like:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE myidx SCHEMA coord GEO age NUMERIC height NUMERIC
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myidx 123 0 FIELDS coord 0,0 age 30 height 40
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myidx 456 0 FIELDS coord 0.1,0.1 age 30 height 40
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myidx 789 0 FIELDS coord 0.1,0.1 age 64 height 64
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myidx 9999 0 FIELDS coord -50,50 age 30 height 40
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myidx 1000 0 FIELDS coord -50,50 age 64 height 64
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH myidx "@coord:[0 0 1 km]"
1) (integer) 1
2) "123"
3) 1) "coord"
   2) "0,0"
   3) "age"
   4) "30"
   5) "height"
   6) "40"
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH myidx "@coord:[0 0 100 km]"
1) (integer) 3
2) "789"
3) 1) "coord"
   2) "0.1,0.1"
   3) "age"
   4) "64"
   5) "height"
   6) "64"
4) "456"
5) 1) "coord"
   2) "0.1,0.1"
   3) "age"
   4) "30"
   5) "height"
   6) "40"
6) "123"
7) 1) "coord"
   2) "0,0"
   3) "age"
   4) "30"
   5) "height"
   6) "40"
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH myidx "@coord:[0 0 100 km] @age:[30 40]"
1) (integer) 2
2) "456"
3) 1) "coord"
   2) "0.1,0.1"
   3) "age"
   4) "30"
   5) "height"
   6) "40"
4) "123"
5) 1) "coord"
   2) "0,0"
   3) "age"
   4) "30"
   5) "height"
   6) "40"
```

Comment: thanks this sound great! is their an index on coord GEO or the engine perform a full scan of all the row ? how to update a row? i don't see any think like a primary key to do so?

Comment: Please open a new question for that, or contact the devs through the mailing list at the project's website.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the moderators don't ding me for this answer,  because it directly answers the question "...the list of memory database that can permit this"

You may consider my company's database system,  eXtremeDB. Please note that, unlike redis, it is not open source or NoSQL. It is an in-memory, structured data DBMS; SQL is optional.

Comment: I will take a look at it, but i would prefer something open source :(

Comment: I should have mentioned in my first reply, we also offer Perst, an open source (dual-license: GPL or commercial) object-oriented database for Java and C#.  Perst also has an implementation of the R-tree index.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with Redis' `SORTED SET` and `GEO` commands.

**Build indexes:**

1. Build a location index with `GEO` commands: `GEOADD location lng1 lat1 uid1 lng2 lat2 uid2`
2. Build an age index with `SORTED SET` commands: `ZADD age 31 uid1 20 uid2`

**Search:**

1. Search by location, and save the result into a temp set: `GEORADIUS location lng lat 100 m store location_result`
2. Get the intersection of the temp set and the age set, and save the result into another temp set: `ZINTERSTORE location_age_result 2 location_result age WEIGHTS 0 1`
3. Filter users that satisfy the age condition: `ZRANGEBYSCORE location_age_result 30 40`

**NOTE:**

When using the `ZINTERSTORE` command, we use the `WEIGHTS` option to only keep the age as the score of the new set.

Comment: thanks for_stack, but i would prefer to avoid to use a temp set that could be (depend of the query) huge, very huge ... i would even prefer to do a full scan and filter on the fly each record ! also i don't only have age, i have much more attribute and can't create an index for each of them

Comment: As I understand it you dont download the temp set to the client, its internal to the server, so not as bad it may seem. MySQL does this sort of thing transaprently. Even using Sphinx, there is such a temporally 'internal' resultset, (controlled by max_matches). A 'full table scan' doesnt fit with REDIS design.